# Difference between drag a control which is in panel and which is in form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I want to drag the control which is in inside the panel. So first i tried change the parent of  control panel to form in mouse down after that i drag it. But its not drag smoothly. If the control is in form and drag the control its drag smoothly what is difference? how to solve it?.

My code is :

```
Private cachedMousePos As Point
Private cachedControlPos As Point
Private isMouseDown As Boolean    

Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown

    Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)

    If (Not target Is Nothing) Then

        Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(target.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
        target.Dock = DockStyle.None
        target.Parent = Me
        target.BringToFront()
        target.Location = pt
        Me.isMouseDown = True
        Me.cachedControlPos = pt
        Me.cachedMousePos = Control.MousePosition

       End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove

    If (Me.isMouseDown) Then

        Dim target As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)

        If (Not target Is Nothing) Then
           Dim x As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - 
           Me.cachedMousePos.X))
           Dim y As Integer = (Me.cachedControlPos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y -
           Me.cachedMousePos.Y))
           target.Location = New Point(x, y)

            'c2 = (c1 + (m2 - m1))

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub HandleDraggableControlMouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp

    Me.cachedControlPos = Point.Empty
    Me.cachedMousePos = Point.Empty
    Me.isMouseDown = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to guess what "smoothly" might mean.  The only thing I see wrong is that you forgot "target.Capture = True" in the MouseDown event handler, required to prevent losing the control when you move the mouse too fast.

Comment: Thanks Sir @HansPassant Its Work `target.Capture = True`